# Delete files inside a subfolder residing inside a bucket on amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

On my s3 I have a bucket called `nba-dataset`. Inside the `nba-dataset` i have a folder called `env`. Inside the folder env i have another folder called `prod-stage`.

So basically The path looks like this `nba-dataset > env > prod-stage`.

I have a files inside prod-stage that I want to delete after x number of days.

So the way i understand is I can apply a [lifecycle rule](https://www.joe0.com/2017/05/24/amazon-s3-how-to-delete-files-older-than-x-days/) on the bucket `nba-dataset`.

The confusing part for me is what should the value be for prefix. Would it be `env/prod-stage` or would it be simply `prod-stage`?

I would appreciate guidance here as there are many files in the subfolders of the bucket `nba-dataset` that I don't want to delete by accident. I only want to delete files inside the prod-stage folder that are older than x days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix is an absolute path so in your case it is `env/prod-stage/`.

There is no such thing as a subfolder within S3, each object has a key which the GUI displays as subfolders by splitting the prefix separately by the `"/"`character.

In fact the interface is simply calling the [list-objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html) method. When you're displayed as being in the env folder the prefix is `env`, then when you move into the subfolder of `prod-stage` the prefix becomes `env/prod-stage`.

Comment: makes sense and do you know if the files older than x days get deleted as soon as the lifecycle rule policy is applied?

Comment: Not quite the actions are queued, "https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/". This is from the https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/ blog :)